# One ajax request, but double received in server, resulting duplicate records when adding new record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use (jQuery) ajax request  to submit form for CRUD methods.
But I'm having this issue for a while.
Sometimes, one ajax request is received double in server, resulting duplicate data when adding new records.
I've checked using Inspect Element, to monitor the ajax request, it only show one request.

Here's the ajax request

```
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",
            data : data,
            cache: false,  
            async: true,
            processData: true,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: setting.url,
```

Does anyone ever having similar issue ?
what caused this ?

Comment: Can you include the `html` part?

Comment: Also the process your data uses to be stored will be very helpful

Comment: The network tab is unlikely to be wrong - we need to see the backend code to understand why that might be inserting twice

Comment: Is the ajax call in an event handler or some other function. You can easily rule out that the event is not being fired multiple times by say putting a `console.log('checking...');` and the handler and then checking to see how many times this is output. Then you can also check to see how many records are returned by your back end - you could start with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you fire ajax call through a element click event suggest you to disabling the button would be to use the .one() method and re-bind the event handler after callback:

```
var clickHandler = function(e){
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'POST',
       async: true,
       dataType: 'json',
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
       cache: false,
       success: function(data){
          $('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
       },
      error: function(){}
   });   
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   return false;
 }
 $('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
```